# how to use x11 as backend for matplotlib on Mountain Lion of Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, matplotlib, x11, backend

I used to use TkAgg as backend on my macbook for matplotlib which was installed from macports. for a while, the plot window was launched in X11. after a latest macports update, it stopped using x11 instead a standalone python window will be used now.

I was wondering if there is a way to instruct matplotlib to open plot window in x11? thanks!

Randy Bin Lin

Comment: Is there any way to remove the dependency on Phython and force an X11 window? Or was X11 support removed from the program?

Comment: Can you check that you are still using the backend you think you are using?

Comment: yes, tcaswell, TkAgg is the one I specified in ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc

Comment: SevenBits, I guess that's the answer I have been looking for to your question (and mine). but so far to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a MacPorts Python and Tk installation, you probably now have the MacPorts `quartz` variant of Tk installed which is a native Cocoa-based Tk and now the default variant.  If you want to use the older X11-based Tk, you can force its use by reinstalling Tk:

```
sudo port upgrade --enforce-variants tk -quartz
```